# 3D Geometry using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-3d

I use the following code to generate a 2D geometry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=350]
\centering
\draw[blue,thick] (0,0) -- (0.0219837,0)-- (0.0219837,0.0168148)-- (0.0056579,0.0168148) -- (0.0052959,0.0127) -- (0.0027051,0.0127) -- (0.0027051,0.0142494)--(0,0.0142494) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black] (0,0) -- (0.0219837,0)-- (0.0219837,0.0168148)-- (0.0056579,0.0168148) -- (0.0052959,0.0127) -- (0.0027051,0.0127) -- (0.0027051,0.0142494)--(0,0.0142494) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{domain.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

**

- **Question**: I'd like to extend the 2D geometry to 3D by having a **30 degree** rotation based on the left most vertical line, i.e. like a **30 degree wedge** for the Profile. In addition, I want to add a smaller wedge shape with a rounded edge (**orange colored profile - also 30 degree**) on top as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Top View:

[image]

**:

Also, **how** to have the 3D geometry in **drawing mode** as follow?
[image]

Thanks in advance for your time. Any insights and help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: What is your figure about?

Comment: Hello, Black Mild. This represents a 30 degree wedge segment of an oxyfuel torch tip.

Comment: @BlackMild Surely that  it seems a cheese :-))))))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example for your last model. It needs `3d` and `perspective` libraries. With `3d` you can change the `canvas` and draw in one of the vertical or horizontal planes. For the small wedge you can do a `shift` of the origin of coordinates and then a `\clip`. I changed your numbers for simplicity.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=-65,
                    line join=round,line cap=round]
  \foreach\i in {0,-30}
    \draw[rotate around z=\i,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
      (0,0) -| (10,8) -- (2.5,8) -- (2.3,6) -| (1.3,7) -| cycle;
  \foreach\i/\j in {10/0,10/8,2.5/8,2.3/6,1.3/6,1.3/7}
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=\j] (0:\i) arc (0:-30:\i);
  % this prevents the circle clip from widening the bounding box
  \useasboundingbox (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south east);
  %
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=7]
    \clip (0,0) circle [radius=1.3];
    \draw[shift={(-15:0.7)},rounded corners] (0,0) -- (-30:1) arc (-30:0:1) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
**Edit:** Now a solid one:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

% colors
\definecolor{side}    {HTML}{879EA4}
\definecolor{top}     {HTML}{AAC7CF}
\definecolor{myorange}{HTML}{EA8032}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=-10,
                    line join=round,line cap=round]
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=7]
    \draw[fill=top] (0,0) -- (-30:1.3) arc (-30:0:1.3) -- cycle;
    \clip (0,0) -- (-30:1.3) arc (-30:0:1.3) -- cycle;
    \draw[shift={(-15:0.7)},rounded corners,fill=myorange] (0,0) -- (-30:1) arc (-30:0:1) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=6,fill=top] 
    (-30:1.3) arc (-30:0:1.3) -- (0:2.3) arc (0:-30:2.3) -- cycle;
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=8,fill=top]
    (-30:2.5) arc (-30:0:2.5) coordinate (1) -- (0:10) arc (0:-30:10) -- cycle;
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=6,fill=side,fill=side]
    (-30:2.3) arc (-30:0:2.3) -- (1) arc (0:-30:2.5) -- cycle;
  \draw[rotate around z=-30,canvas is xz plane at y=0,fill=side]
    (0,0) -| (10,8) -- (2.5,8) -- (2.3,6) -| (1.3,7) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, @Juan

Comment: Hi @Juan, is there a way to draw the 1st one, I.e. solid body as well? The smaller wedge would have a different color as shown than the rest of the body. I would also like to label different faces.

Comment: @Rahman, see my edit. And for the labels you only need to put a node in the desired position.

Comment: Thanks, @Juan. This is great and I appreciate your time.